# MYSQL Timestampdiff output formatting last two decimals

Tags: mysql

Simple question

What is the best way to change the output so that it only displays the last two decimals?

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, start_it,start_qa)
```

So that the output of '13.2500' displays as '13.25'.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would do this in the application layer.  If you insist on doing it in the database, you can use `format()`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, start_it,start_qa), 2)
```